# Does Django multiple database support generate tables for only some specific apps in a database

Tags: python, django, multiple-databases

I aim to store history of tables using django-simple-history library in a separated database from the main one. When I run `migrate --database=the_second_db`, Django generates all tables for all apps in the second database.

How can I make it just generate some specific tables for specific apps that I need in the second database( history tables)?

Comment: You have to migrate only those apps that you want to see in the database. You can make a copy of your app and keep only those migrations that you want to see in your second database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible by using [Django Database Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers), also you must define multiple database configuration on the `DATABASES` constant on the your project **settings.py** file.